# URL to resource as additional (eloquent) model attribute

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

When retrieving models from database and sending them to the client I want to include for each model the url to that resource.

Let's take as example this `Article` model, with:

- id
- title
- content
- etc.

Storing the url to an article in the DB doesn't make sense, because it can be easily made up from id and title:

ex: http://www.example.com/articles/article_id/article_title

So, this is what I am doing now:

I use the `$appends` array:

```
/**
 * Additional attributes
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $appends = array('article_url');
```

and created a getter for `article_url`:

```
/**
 * Get the article url attribute
 *
 * @return string
 */
protected function getArticleUrlAttribute()
{
    return $this->exists
        ? url('articles', $parameters = array(
            $this->getKey(),
            Str::title(Str::limit($this->title, 100))
        ))
        : null;
}
```

This works just fine. The problem is, that probably the model should not include any logic for creating urls. What is a good approach for this problem? Where should I create the 
url to the article before sending it to the client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sort of logic would usually go in whatever your framework's routing engine is. For instance, since it sounds like you're using Laravel, you'd probably make a **[Named Route](http://laravel.com/docs/routing#named-routes)** -- call it, say, "canonical_article".

Then you can use the `link_to_route` helper to have your framework generate the URL.